# What is considered overloading the main thread?

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface, timer, grand-central-dispatch

I am displaying information from a data model on a user interface. My current approach to doing so is by means of delegation as follows:

```
@protocol DataModelDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)updateUIFromDataModel;
@end
```

I am implementing the delegate method in my controller class as follows, using GCD to push the UI updating to the main thread:

```
- (void)updateUIFromDataModel {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // Code to update various UI controllers
        // ...
        // ...

    });
}
```

What I am concerned about is that in some situations, this method can be called very frequently (~1000 times per second, each updating multiple UI objects), which to me feels very much like I am 'spamming' the main thread with commands.

Is this too much to be sending to the main thread? If so does anyone have any ideas on what would be the best way of approaching this?

I have looked into `dispatch_apply`, but that appears to be more useful when coalescing data, which is not what I am after - I really just want to skip updates if they are too frequent so only a sane amount of updates are sent to the main thread!

I was considering taking a different approach and implementing a timer instead to constantly poll the data, say every 10 ms, however since the data updating tends to be sporadic I feel that it would be wasteful to do so.

Combining both approaches, another option I have considered would be to wait for an update message and respond by setting the timer to poll the data at a set interval, and then disabling the timer if the data appears to have stopped changing. But would this be over-complicating the issue, and would the sane approach be to simply have a constant timer running?

**edit:** *Added an answer below showing the adaptations using a dispatch source*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to use a [Dispatch Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html) with type `DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_DATA_OR` which lets you post events repeatedly and have libdispatch combine them together for you. When you have something to post, you use `dispatch_source_merge_data` to let it know there's something new to do. Multiple calls to `dispatch_source_merge_data` will be coalesced together if the target queue (in your case, the main queue) is busy.

Comment: I have taken a look at this, but am a little confused about how to implement it.. When building a custom dispatch source it appears the only options are to combine data using a logical AND or logical OR, but what I want to receive is the most recent value that has been sent only, and discard all of the calls that have queued up due to the busy main thread?

Comment: If all you want is the most recent value, you can just store that somewhere else (e.g. a global) and overwrite it (in a thread-safe way!) each time you send a new value. You can then read that on your main thread, which will be the latest value.

Comment: Ahh, I get it - so essentially use the dispatch source just as a means of coalescing the update notifications when things get too busy and ignore the value it gives and just use the block that responds to read from elsewhere? I didn't think of that. I suppose in that respect I could actually use `DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_DATA_ADD` and add one for each message that is sent - the resulting value could then be used to monitor how many messages are being skipped due to the main thread being too busy to handle them all. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

I have been experimenting with dispatch sources and got it working as expected now - Here is how I have adapted my class implementation in case it is of use to anyone who comes across this question:

```
@implementation AppController {
@private
    dispatch_source_t _gcdUpdateUI;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {

    // Added the following code to set up the dispatch source event handler:

    _gcdUpdateUI = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_DATA_ADD, 0, 0, 
                                          dispatch_get_main_queue());
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(_gcdUpdateUI, ^{

        // For each UI element I want to update, pull data from model object:
        // For testing purposes - print out a notification:
        printf("Data Received. Messages Passed: %ld\n", 
               dispatch_source_get_data(_gcdUpdateUI));
    });

dispatch_resume(_gcdUpdateUI);

}
```

And now in the delegate method I have removed the call to `dispatch_async`, and replaced it with the following:

```
- (void)updateUIFromDataModel {

  dispatch_source_merge_data(_gcdUpdateUI, 1);

}
```

This is working absolutely fine for me. Now Even during the most intense data updating the UI stays perfectly responsive.

Although the `printf()` output was a very crude way of checking if the coalescing is working, a quick scrolling back up the console output showed me that the majority of the messages print outs had a value 1 (easily 98% of them), however there were the intermittent jumps to around 10-20, reaching a peak value of just over 100 coalesced messages around a time when the model was sending the most update messages.

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If the app beach-balls under heavy load, then you've blocked the main thread for too long and you need to implement a coalescing strategy for UI updates. If the app remains responsive to clicks, and doesn't beach-ball, then you're fine.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, when it get's busy it's not beach balling, but performance does appear to be impacted a little. The UI stays responsive but ever so slightly delayed, so I guess i'm close to blocking the main thread when under heavy data load.

Comment: A coalescing strategy that might work for you is to use two different timers.  Set and reset timer 1 each time the data is changed.  Don't update the view until that timer fires. Timer 2 is to make sure the data gets updated at least every n seconds (if it changed) in case Timer 1 never has a chance to fire.

Comment: If at some point I need a constant update I think this is the way I will go, I like how this can provide both a short burst maximum update speed and a maximum time between updates for slow periods.. If I decided to use this method would you think adding a `BOOL` flag to something along the lines of 'viewUpdateRequested' (which can be set by the delegate method), and then for the timer's `onTick:` methods check if this flag has been set before performing the update?